# Change position of label of Matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a simple pie chart with the percentage and label of each slice indicated. The percentage marks and labels are right in the middle of each of the pie slices, but I want these two to be moved to to a different part of the slice as indicated in the figure below, such that all labels are on the left side of the figure.

Is there a way to do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})

labels = 'A', 'B', 'C'
sizes = [5, 20, 75]
explode = (0.1, 0, 0)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is actually easy. Follow these steps:

1 - Drop label parameter from ax1.pie. Let it be just:
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)

2 - Add plt.legend() after ax1.axis("equal") line.

3 - Pass your labels as an argument to plt.legend() i.e. plt.legend(labels).

4 - If you are still not happy with the location of the legend, there is one more parameter you can manipulate which is bbox_to_anchor.

5 - Pass bbox_to_anchor as the second parameter to plt.legend() and give it two numbers in form of tuple like: bbox_to_anchor = (2, 3). Play around with it until it is where you want it to be.

Comment: That is one way to solve this that I haven't thought about. But now the labels are in a separate legend. Is there no way to have the labels be right next to the slices as in my example, but just so that label 'C' is shifted more towards the left of the figure instead of in the middle of the green slice?

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question in the beginning. So, you want one particular label to be shifted the left side. I do not know anything about that but alternatively you can add the labels to the legend too and move them around with bbox_to_anchor argument.

Comment: Indeed, moving a single label was my intent. But your solution is also one that would work for me.